# Implementing dynamic selectors and showing up corresponding image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I'm trying to implement a functionality:

1. Show list of items on the left
2. Dynamic selector loop each item (dashed rectangle in the image below)
3. On the right it should show an image for an item that has selector on it
4. Items' names and images will be pulled out from a storage

Question: Is this something that can be implemented with jQuery or something else?

It'd helpful if could recommend any related resources.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of this code. Replace the id's and class names with your ones.

```js
var list = ["cat","dog","elephant","lion"];
var listImg = ["cat","dog","elephant","lion"];

createListPanel();
function createListPanel()
{
var parent = $("#displayPanel").find("td").eq(0);
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
{
parent.append("<div class='list' id="+i+">"+list[i]+"</div>");
}
$(".list").click(function(){
$("#detailDisplay").html(listImg[this.id]);
});
}
```

```css
.list:hover{
  background-color: #ffcccc;
}

.list{
  background-color: #ffe6e6;
    width:150px;
}
#displayPanel
{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "displayPanel">
<table width="100%">
<tr><td ></td><td><div id="detailDisplay"></div></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

You can replace the text in the ListImg with your image url